# VSCODE intellisense working with SOBJECT fields, but not showing variables just created

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, autocomplete

Salesforce VSCode extension pack intelliSense seems to be working with nearly everything including intelliSense for showing all fields of SOBJECTS except it is not show variables I have just created.

For example, intellisense will not show me the 'matchingContact' variable I just created,
once I have typed in matchingContact. < once I enter the '.' intellisense shows me all of the object's fields. I Have java 11 set up. Pretty much everything seems to be working fine except this one thing. It is still pretty annoying though.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a feature of the Salesforce Extension Pack and instead a setting in your VSCODE Editor.

Go to Settings> TextEditor Settings and Enable "**Show Variables**".

[image]

Check the official docs here and below [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) should be turned on

```
   //When enabled IntelliSense shows `value`-suggestions.
    `"editor.suggest.showValues": true`,

    //When enabled IntelliSense shows `variable`-suggestions.
      `"editor.suggest.showVariables": true`,

    // When enabled IntelliSense shows `text`-suggestions.
        `"editor.suggest.showWords": true`,
```

The other thing i can recommend is use an extension like [TanNine](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TabNine.tabnine-vscode) that uses deep learning to start recommending code suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did have variable suggestions enabled, which is weird, but tabnine works like a charm.

Comment: @cre Please accept the answer as it worked for you.